# conditional visible form field

Tags: 8

How can i make the second field visible depending on the value selected in the first field ?

i have tried this but it does not work :

```
 $form['call-to-actions-widget']['call-to-actions-widget_select'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('widget options'),
      '#description' => $this->t('choisir un widget'),
      '#options' => [
        'none'=>$this->t('none'),
        'year_navigation' => $this->t('exposed filter :year'),
        'row_max_unset' => $this->t('more publications ( block refresh )'),
        'internal_link' => $this->t('more publications ( internal link )'),
      ],
      '#default_value' => (!empty($config['call-to-actions-widget_select'])) ? $config['call-to-actions-widget_select'] : 'none'
    ];

    $form['call-to-actions-widget']['internal_link'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('internal link'),
      '#description' => $this->t('de type /node/56'),
      '#default_value' => (!empty($config['internal_link'])) ? $config['internal_link'] : ''
    ];

    $form['call-to-actions-widget']['internal_link']['#states'] = [
      'visible' => [
        [
          [':input[name="call-to-actions-widget_select"]' => ['value' => 'internal_link']]
        ],
      ],
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$form['call-to-actions-widget']['internal_link']['#states'] = [
  'visible' => [
    ':input[name="call-to-actions-widget_select"]' => ['value' => 'internal_link'],
  ],
];
```

In case when it doesn't work use another selector

```
':input[name="call-to-actions-widget[call-to-actions-widget_select]"]'
```

Or check in the browser name of the needed field. See e.g. where the name is password[pass1]

[image: name is password[pass1]]